# Angular 2 call a function in another component (Comp2) from the html of comp1

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

--- Component 1---------------

```
<div>
<li><a href="#" (click)="getFactsCount()"> Instance 2 </a></li>
```

However, the implementation of getFactsCount() is in another component. Should I use @output/ emitter or something? 
----Component 2-----------

```
@component({
selector:'comp2'
templateUrl:'comp2.html'
})
export class Component2 implements OnInit{
getFactsCount(){

console.log("Function inside component2");

}
}
```

Comment: or DI or service or template reference variable...

Comment: Why don't you use a service here?instead of component

Comment: @jitender you mean to say observable? Could you paste a snippet as how i can use it?

Comment: @yurzui I didn't get you. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: You should at least provide information about how they are connected. And i think you have already read docs https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: @yurzui They're two independent components, there's no parent-child relationship.

Comment: Then service is a good way to go.https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: @yurzui Yeah ! I will go for service but these two components are not Parent and child. It's actually there's a drop down of multiple instances[like 1,2,3,4,5] and if i click on instance 1 it will basically call the REST api pass the instance number as a param in the REST call to display the data.

Comment: @yurzui Could you please help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46448552/angular-2-im-not-able-to-create-a-behavior-subject-for-a-number-variable-type

Answer (score 2):

**Correct Approach**: You should either use an [angular service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4) or an [event emitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter).

To answer your question : In your component 2 call component 1 function as below:

```
let comp = new Component1();
let count = comp.getFactsCount();
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to add an emitter or something ? This looks like more of a java code :)

Comment: Looking at the updated information in your comments, I would suggest you to use a service as the components do not have a parent-child relationship the event emitter won't help in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You should put common logic in service something like:-

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    getFactsCount(): any {   
        //some logic here 
    } 
}
```

Then in component constructor inject something like

```
@component({
selector:'comp1',
templateUrl:'comp1.html',
providers:[MyService]
})
export class Component1 implements OnInit{

constructor( private service : MyService ) {
}
getFactCount():any{
 return this.service.getFactCount()
 }
```

You can register your service  globally (in app.module if you are using cli) also

Comment: This is cool :) Could you please split the code interms of component 1 and component 2? Component1 html code where i will listen to click event and once it's triggered all i have to do is call the function present in component 2! Should i put that function in service instead of component 2?

Comment: offcourse you should put your function in service not in component 2 if you need to call it in both component

Comment: see update answer for component1 you could call it in your html in the same way as you were doing it before